# How can I put Rating Bar in Android

Tags: android, ratingbar

I'm trying to put rating bar stars instead of spinner on this code but getting some error again and again. Can anybody help me please. Thanks

```
    <RatingBar
    android:id="@+id/review_rating"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:numStars="3"
    android:stepSize="1.0"
    android:entries="@array/rating"
    android:rating="2.0" />
    </RatingBar>
```

AddReviewActivity.class

```
package com.example.facilitiesreviewapp;

public class AddReviewActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    String id;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        setTitle("Add Reviews");
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_add_review);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.add_review, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        Intent intent;

        if (id == R.id.search_station) {
            intent = new Intent(this, SearchActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
        else if (id == R.id.add_station) {
            intent = new Intent(this, AddStationActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

        Intent intent = getIntent();
        id = intent.getStringExtra(SearchActivity.EDITID);
    }

    public void saveReview(View view) {
        //Get fields
        EditText dateView = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.review_date);
        EditText commentView = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.review_comments);
        ratingBar ratingView = (ratingBar) findViewById(R.id.review_rating);
        Spinner featureView = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.review_feature);

        //Get Content
        String review_date = dateView.getText().toString();
        String review_comment = commentView.getText().toString();
        String review_rating = ratingView.getSelectedItem().toString();
        String review_feature = featureView.getSelectedItem().toString();

        //Validation
        boolean errors = false;
        String error_msg = "";

        if (review_date.equals("")) {
            errors = true;
            error_msg += "Date field is required";
        }

        if (errors) {
            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
            builder.setMessage(error_msg).setTitle("Error in submission");
            AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
            dialog.show();
        }
        else {
            DbHandler dbh = new DbHandler(this);
            SQLiteDatabase db = dbh.getWritableDatabase();

            ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
            values.put(DbHandler.ReviewHandler.COLUMN_NAME_STATION_ID, id);
            values.put(DbHandler.ReviewHandler.COLUMN_NAME_DATE, review_date);
            values.put(DbHandler.ReviewHandler.COLUMN_NAME_FEATURE, review_feature);
            values.put(DbHandler.ReviewHandler.COLUMN_NAME_RATING, review_rating);
            values.put(DbHandler.ReviewHandler.COLUMN_NAME_COMMENTS, review_comment);

            long newRowID = db.insert(DbHandler.ReviewHandler.Table_Name, "", values);

            db.close();
            dbh.close();

            Intent intent = new Intent(this, ReviewsActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra(SearchActivity.EDITID, id);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please post the error ?

Comment: You are ending you RatingBar element twice. Once with /> and once with </RatingBar> For any other help we need to see the error/s you get.